# Degree of ODE involving $\sin(y')$ and $\cos(y')$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

**Quick question** :

What will be the degree of the following first order ordinary differential equation ?
$$\sin\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)= c$$

According to my teacher, the degree is not defined. But I fail to understand why.

In my defense, I can rewrite this ODE as : $$\sin\left(\frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{\pi}{4}\right) = \frac{c}{\sqrt{2}}$$ $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{c}{\sqrt{2}}\right) - \frac{\pi}{4}$$

So, shouldn't the degree be just 1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, there are actually infinitely many possible values for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ since one can add $2\pi n$ (for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$) when you take $\sin^{-1}$ of each side. Thus, your rearrangement is not the same as the initial ODE.

As for why the degree is undefined, the degree of a first order ODE is usually defined as the highest power of $\frac{dy}{dx}$. However, since sine and cosine are not powers, we can't immediately give a degree to the initial ODE. In fact, one might even argue the degree is $\infty$, as we can replace sine and cosine with their Taylor expansions such that the equation consists of infinitely many powers of $\frac{dy}{dx}$.